# Selecting rows with Vuetify v-data-table + v-model is not working as expected and auto-sorts my selected rows messing me up

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using the Vuetify v-data-table component, and I am trying to select rows on my table and convert them to csv. So I would like to select all rows, have my selected rows in an array of objects, and then click a button to perform a function that does the conversion, however I am facing an issue with the v-data-table component, when I select the rows, instead of them being pushed into my array based on the order they are selected (clicking on checkboxes), they are not pushed into my v-model array as expected, it's as if every time I click on a row, the v-model or v-data-table component sorts the resultant "selected" array by my item-key ascending, even though I do not have that set, for example, here is my code:

```
<template>
<v-card>
  <v-data-table
    v-model='selected'
    :headers='headers'
    :items='results'
    item-key='id'
    show-select
    dense
  ></v-data-table>
</v-card>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: () => ({
        headers: [
    { value: 'id', text: 'ID', fixed: true, active: false },
    { value: 'd_submission_date', text: 'Date of Submission', active: true },
    { value: 'i_sample_count', text: 'Number of Samples', active: true },
    { value: 'i_file_count', text: 'Number of Files', active: true },
    { value: 'created_at', text:'Created At', active: false },
    { value: 'updated_at', text: 'Updated At', active: false }
]
        results: [{
    "id": 1203,
    "d_submission_date": "2021-04-08",
    "created_at": "2021-04-08T18:19:31.011561Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-04-14T21:42:35.285029Z",
    "i_sample_count": 1,
    "i_file_count": 0
},
{
    "id": 1202,
    "d_submission_date": "2021-04-08",
    "created_at": "2021-04-08T18:19:31.011561Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-04-14T21:42:35.285029Z",
    "i_sample_count": 1,
    "i_file_count": 0
},
{
    "id": 1201,
    "d_submission_date": "2021-04-08",
    "created_at": "2021-04-08T18:19:31.011561Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-04-14T21:42:35.285029Z",
    "i_sample_count": 1,
    "i_file_count": 0
}],
        selected: []
    })
</script>
```

So if I select the row with id 1203 by clicking the checkbox next to it, the object will be pushed into my selected array via the two-way binding with v-model, so "selected = [{
"id": 1203,
"d_submission_date": "2021-04-08",
"created_at": "2021-04-08T18:19:31.011561Z",
"updated_at": "2021-04-14T21:42:35.285029Z",
"i_sample_count": 1,
"i_file_count": 0
}]"

But then let's say after doing this I select the row with id 1201, and then the row with id 1202, I would expect my selected array to be "selected = [{ id:1203, etc. }, { id:1201, etc. }, { id: 1202, etc. }]" BUT INSTEAD, I get this array: "selected = [{ id:1201, etc. }, { id:1202, etc. }, { id: 1203, etc. }]"

So for some reason the data is getting auto-sorted by my item-key ascending and I have no idea why or how to stop this! I have tried so many v-data-table props like sort-by-desc and sort-by='id' to no avail, has anyone else experienced this or have any idea what to do, any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need them in specific order? or just the order they were pressed on? because if you need them in specific order you can do a sort method on the array before converting them to svc

Comment: @NoyGafni I need them in the order they appear on the data table, so like if I order them all by id descending, when I "select all", the data in my array should be ordered by descending as well, not ordered by ascending from index 0 to the end, which is what is happening

Comment: Ok so according to the vuetify source code the selection values are saved as an object with the item-key as the key, and the item as the value, and then they emit the `Object.values(selection)`. This explains why the selection value is sorted by the item-key, because javascript sorts the object according to its keys. So for conclusion you can achieve your goal only by sorting the array by yourself according to the current sortBy and sortDesc. There is no way to achieve that with vuetify - but you can open a feature request issue if you want

Comment: Hi @NoyGafni, thank you so much for actually diving into the source code to help me, I was wondering if you could check out my other post instead of this one, I think I was not describing my issue that well, and I explained my issue better here, please let me know if this changes your answer/my solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67202306/different-vuetify-v-data-table-behaviour-between-different-data-sets-issue

Comment: I am sorry but i don't know why it sometimes happens, and sometimes don't. I would suggest to sort the array with the values you want before performing actions on then like i said in my previous comment.

Comment: @NoyGafni could you point me to the file in the source code you see this, I can't find it

Comment: it is in `VDataIterator.ts` - the data that holds the selected items is `this.selection`, the `select` method is called when you press row checkbox, and you can see the return value in the `selection` watcher

Comment: @NoyGafni I found the issue, apparently v-data-table treats item-keys that are numbers without alphabetical characters differently than item-keys with numbers + alphabetical characters, absolutely INSANE

Answer (score 1):

The v-data-table treats the v-model array differently based on the item-key, I had tables where my item-key was a string with alphabetical characters AND numbers in the key string, and then item-keys that were JUST numbers (but still a string), and the component treated them differently in the v-model, absolutely insane

Comment: Thank you so much. The doc does not advertise item-key prop enough